# how to set a large image in image view

Tags: android

I have an image view and I want to set an image on it. The size of the image is 7,707,446  bytes. Whenever I try to set the layout, the app crashes and the error is *out of memory error*.can anyone suggest me how to solve it.The xml is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/image" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap picture=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard...");
    int width = picture.getWidth();
    int height = picture.getWidth();
    float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    int newWidth = 70;
    int newHeight = (int) (70 / aspectRatio);       
    picture= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(picture, newWidth, newHeight, true);


public static Bitmap decodeImage(String arrayList_image) {

        URL aURL;

        try {

            aURL = new URL(arrayList_image);

            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();

            conn.connect();

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

            bis.close();

            is.close();

            return bm;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i suggest u to try this and display your image according the Device.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(),drawableId);
            int w = bmp.getWidth();
            int h = bmp.getHeight();

            System.out.println("OrgWidth : " + w);
            System.out.println("orgHeight : " + h);

            int targetWidth = (screenWidth * w)/iPadWidth;
            int targetHeight = (screenHeight * h)/iPadHeight;

            System.out.println("TargetWidth : " + targetWidth);
            System.out.println("TargetHeight : " + targetHeight);

            int[] arrWidthHeight = {targetWidth,targetHeight};

            // This for Slove the out of Memory problem

            int newWidth = 110;
            int newHeight = 110;
            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / w;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / h;

            Matrix bMatrix = new Matrix();
            bMatrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h , bMatrix, true);
```

First fetch the Image from resources and find new height and width of image according to device and after scale this image as purpose for solve the out of memory here.

This for find height and width according to device height and width..

```
WindowManager winManager = (WindowManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            screenWidth = winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            screenHeight = winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

            System.out.println("Screen Width : " + screenWidth);
            System.out.println("Screen Height : " + screenHeight);
```

and  use bitmap to get image height and width witch like a ipathwidth and ipathHeight ok now 
Happy

Comment: can you please tell what is screen width and iPadwidth

Comment: screen width is device width according the device and ipathwidth witch image you use to display in your activity..\

Comment: generally i create one method witch return me new height and width with imagedrawable for set image background..

Comment: so,i have to calculate the screen height and iPad width...can you please tell me how?

Comment: I tried your code but it does not works for me.The width and height of my image is 640,7140

Comment: Friend i suggest you no any give you whole code just guide you it`s whole code i give which already work for me very well.so try to this another time  best luck

Comment: Ok Improve my answer witch help some one

Answer (score 0):

See [Loading Large Bitmaps Effectively](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

You could create a function to calculate a downscaling factor:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

And then use this to load a scaled Bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Thus if you wanted to load a 100x100 pixel thumbnail into your ImageView, you'd just use:

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(
    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, 100, 100)
);
```